# How to separate files, number wise using regular expressions in java/shell?

Tags: java, shell

I want to separate below numbers like as(00 to 04, 10 to 14, 20 to 24)
00000000000
00000000001
00000000002
00000000003
00000000010
00000000011
00000000012
00000000014
00000000020
00000000021
00000000022
00000000024
00000000030
00000000031
00000000032
00000000034
00000000100
00000000101
00000000110
00000000111
00000000120
00000000121

Comment: Are you using shell (If so, which one? Basic sh, bash, zsh, etc.) or java? They're very different environments...

Comment: And what do you mean by separate?

Answer (score 1):

You can find each match with the following regex:

```
\d{11}\b
```

Here is a test

https://regex101.com/r/zruNcQ/1

If you need to create ranges only with continuous values (even though does not really respect your example, but it wasn't really clear). You could use a `Scanner` to read each number with a while loop (no need for a regex) and check if the new number read interrupts the continuity of the current range.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader("test.txt"));

        int from, to, temp;
        List<Range> list = new ArrayList<>();

        if (sc.hasNext()) {
            //Reading the first range number and assigning it to the start and end of range
            from = to = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());

            //Reading the rest of the numbers
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                //Reading the number
                temp = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());

                //Checking if the range is being continued
                if (temp == to + 1) {
                    to = temp;

                    //Checking if the continuous range has been interrupted and saving the previous range
                } else if (temp > to + 1) {
                    list.add(new Range(from, to));
                    from = to = temp;
                }
            }

            //Saving the last range
            list.add(new Range(from, to));
        }

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}

class Range {
    int from, to;

    public Range(int from, int to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("(%d - %d)", from, to);
    }
}
```